# Cannot set options on Vite Glob Import

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite

I'm trying to import using the Vite Glob Import functionality, as described on their Features [Features](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html) page.

Below is the line I'm using:

`const posts = import.meta.glob("./mdx/*.mdx", { eager: true });`

However, the `{ eager: true}` section is producing the following error(s) on build:

```
Argument of type '{ eager: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GlobOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'eager' does not exist in type 'GlobOptions'.ts(2345)
```

Does anyone know of any documentation, or any reason these won't be working, I can't find anything about it online?

I've tried other options on the documentation such as `{ as: 'raw'}` but none of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `tsconfig.json` file to add the below:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["vite/client"]
  }
}
```

Then restart your IDE. Vite's TypeScript types should be picked up, and the error should be gone.

---

On a side note, Vite extend the `import.meta` object, by adding some utility functions. `glob` is one such function, which allows to resolve files given a glob pattern.

If Vite's type declarations aren't picked up, you'll get the issue you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thank you! This already existed in my tsconfig, but it prompted me to think there was a different issue. I was using my default VSCode tsconfig, not the workspace version!